# Performing load test on Tibco JMS endpoint with JMeter

Tags: jmeter, tibco-ems

I want to perform load test on a Tibco JMS endpoint using JMeter. The endpoint is a JMS Queue Receiver that will reply to the JMS Message to end the sessions. I have done a lot of googling regarding what parameters to fill in each field of the JMS Point-to-Point sampler with no success. Attached is a screen shot of the Jmeter window. I am not sure whether this is the right sampler to use or if I should use Publisher. Either way, I do not know what to fill in each of these fields. I am currently stuck at the JNDI name Request queue field. When I put my queue name for the JMS on Tibco, I get an error that that name is not found. Leaving the field blank is also problematic. What should I fill in this field to make the request work?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We don't know your topic/queue names so we cannot help, you can ask around, see the application you're trying to simulate configuration or use [Graphical Administration Tool for TIBCO® EMS](https://community.tibco.com/modules/graphical-administration-tool-tibcor-ems) to explore the endpoint and identify the proper queues for messages sending/receiving. For sending the messages you might need to set [`JMS_TIBCO_SENDER` JNDI property](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/enterprise_message_service/7.0.0-august-2012/doc/html/tib_ems_api_reference/api/dotNET/html/F_TIBCO_EMS_Tibems_JMS_TIBCO_SENDER.htm)

You might also be interested in [Building a JMS Testing Plan - Apache JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/building-jms-testing-plan-apache-jmeter/) article

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, maybe what I was looking for is a reference with brief explanations of what to put in each text box in relation to tibco. The last link article you shared is helpful if you are using activemq. In tibco ecosystem, I keep getting errors no matter what i fill in those fields. I was hoping for a screenshot like one above with sample data and a brief explanation in tibco context. But i have decided to use loadrunner coz examples for what am looking for online are written in java, which was easier for me to manipulate to fit my needs.

Comment: Are you able to achieve this using JMeter @Sean

Comment: No, I decided to use LoadRunner instead. I never bothered to look for a JMeter solution

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem...
And turns out the queue I tried to test was not created manually in GEMS and there was one property "isStatic" somehow set to false[image]

After manually creating a new queue with isStatic = true, jMeter was finally able to send messages to my queue.
Below is my JMeter configuration for reference:
[image]